# NPM not working. Cannot find module 'strip ansi'

Tags: node.js, npm

I just downloaded node but npm is  not working. whenever I use a npm comman I get Error: cannot find module 'strip-ansi'.

Comment: Is this a temporary problem? Can you reproduce it on other machines? Can you install *any other* NPM module?

Comment: I can not reproduce it on other machines since I dont know how I got this error. I cannot install any other npm module because I cannot enter any npm commands.

Comment: You've got a lot of problems if you can't enter any commands. Try reinstalling Node? I don't know what you've done, you haven't really said much here.

Comment: I dont know what happend either. So I reinstalled node (repair) but it keep coming up

Comment: If you're new to Node you might want to find some [community support](https://nodejs.org/en/get-involved/) to get someone to help familiarize you with how to use this tool. The [IRC channel](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=node.js) might be best.

Comment: It's working now. I had to manually install an older version of npm. I downloaded 1.4 and put in the nodejs folder. then updated it to the latest verison and now it is working.. so weird..

Answer (score 15):

For what it's worth, this ended up happening to me, using nvm on mac. `npm cache clean` didn't work. I ended up reinstalling via nvm:

```
$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh | bash
$ nvm install node
```

Answer (score 7):

I was stuck on this problem too. Finally, I solved the issue by adding value `'.js', '.ts'` to `resolve.extensions` in my `webpack.config.js`.  If you are using webpack too, this may help.

Comment: This was the fix for me. Also, npm's cache is supposed to work fine nowadays (you get some info on this by trying to `npm cache clean`). IMO you should try this first if you're using webpack + typescript

Comment: I had a similar problem with different solutions. the `resolve.modules` were set to `[path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')...` where the webpack config file was not in the root. When fixed this with `../node_modules` instead it worked.

Answer (score 4):

just reinstall strip using `npm install strip --save` this kind of error occurs because some file may be corrupt in strip library if this will not work you can try also `npm install` you will solve this error.

Comment: It doesnt work. I cant type any npm commands. I will get the same error msg

Comment: In my case it was just `npm install strip-ansi --save` to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I hit this same issue. I tried to update npm after a fresh Node.js install, but cancelled in the middle because it appeared stuck. Reinstalling Node.js didn't help.

I resolved the issue by deleting the temporary `npm` files in my `AppData` folder (for me on Windows, I found it in `c:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm`). Then I was able to run `npm` normally again.

Hope that helps!

Comment: on mac i solved with: brew uninstall --force node; sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/; brew install node

Answer (score 1):

It solved for me by going to the NPM install folder at `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm` and running the `yarn` command. After running it successfully, NPM started working normally.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my next js application. What i did was uninstall strip-ansi(npm uninstall strip-ansi) and then reinstall (npm install strip-ansi)

Answer (score 0):

Clear your temporary paths of npm and this is solution.
if you're using linux:

go to $ cd /tmp/

search by npm-* folders

and remove all.

Answer (score -2):

Solved by doing `npm cache clean` and then `npm install`

Comment: This does not work, the error happens before npm can even run.

Comment: Well i just shared what worked for me, eventually this is easy to test before reinstalling the whole thing.