# Docker node instance fails to run gulp command with cannot find module 'strip-ansi'

Tags: node.js, docker, gulp

When running my docker container I get the following error

```
    Error: Cannot find module 'strip-ansi'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/string-width/index.js:2:17)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
```

Even though I have both added strip-ansi to my package.json and am manually calling `npm i strip-ansi` in my Dockerfile.
I'm not even sure what is trying to use strip-ansi, and why it can't find it in my node_modules folder.

I have checked all through the similar stack articles, have tried different node versions (6, 8, 10, 11), have tried moving it to devDependencies. The only thing I have not tried is the one recommendation from [this stack article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39232406/npm-not-working-cannot-find-module-strip-ansi) to use nvm to download node, as I'm not sure how to do that within my Dockerfile (they use curl)

Here is my Dockerfile, I'm not sure what else I can provide

```
FROM node:10.15.0

WORKDIR /html

RUN npm install -g gulp
RUN npm install -g bower
RUN npm install gulp
RUN npm link gulp
RUN npm install strip-ansi

COPY package*.json ./
COPY bower.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN bower install --allow-root

ADD . .

CMD gulp prodBuildNoDeploy
```

My build and run commands:

```
docker build -t clientparticipation .
docker run -it --name=cp clientparticipation
```

If I knew exactly where this was going wrong, I might know what more I could provide, could it be related to the gulpfile?

I have never got this project running so I'm not entirely certain what the expected output should be, judging by the gulpfile it should just build for production.

Comment: Can you include your `docker run` command or `docker-compose.yml` file in the question?  Why wouldn't you run the build command as a RUN step, building an image out of the assembled package?

Comment: @DavidMaze edited the question, also added a solution that I'd love input on (don't know why it worked)

Comment: @DavidMaze Also as to building as a RUN step? Simply because I didn't know it was an option, I'm new to Docker.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `WORKDIR /html` solved the issue. I need to go back to Docker docs to see why, or to try and solve what I was doing wrong because I think using a WORKDIR is correct here.

I would love some input here on either how to get it working with WORKDIR or input on why I should not be using WORKDIR.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall node

delete npm/node/nodemodule folder from c drive

install again